# Vuex ORM define id´s for objects inside properties

Tags: orm, vuex-orm

I get a response from an API looking like this:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "h": {
        "event": "EVENT",
        "date": 1621265337566,
        "edited": "me",
        "changed": [
            {
                "old": "",
                "new": "test",
                "field": "Name",
                "class": "form"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to represent this in a Vuex ORM Model. In my understanding this should result in 3 Model Classes. One for the whole object, one for "h" and one for "changed". Vuex ORM provides methods to join these like [hasMany](https://vuex-orm.org/guide/model/relationships.html#one-to-one) but these seem to work with set id´s only which the api response does not provide.

Does anyone know how to represent this response in Vuex ORM ?